# Conditional string concatenation/building in JSF

Tags: jsf, web, conditional-statements

I'm trying to convert a JSP Page to JSF (no JSP code allowed), but have stumbled upon an issue. 
Note: This is academic, so no "dirty" solution will do.

I have jsp code that sets the image source and alt text of an image depending on various conditions. There are concatenations and switch conditions. This is inside a loop.

Now, I can reproduce the loop that goes through all the values, like this:

```
  <ui:repeat value="#{gameapi.game.fieldsList}" var="field">                                          
     <h:graphicImage id="field#{field.fieldNr}" styleClass="field#{field.fieldNr}" 
                                                            url="..." alt="" title=""/>                                          
  </ui:repeat>
```

However, there's a total of over 20 combinations for the image url and alt text. Obviously, I doubt writing a conditionally rendered or chosen graphicImage Tag for every possibility is an elegant solution, since this would only get uglier with every additional combination.
I also cannot create those strings in the underlying java code, since that would violate the idea of separating view, model and controller.

So what is the best solution to do this? It seems like a huge weakness of JSF.

Comment: For a total of more than 20 combinations the view is definitely _not_ the right place. So in my opinion you would violate MVC if you put this logic in the _facelet._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a variation on the [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) pattern. You can have managed beans that are dedicated to view logic separate from the business logic managed beans.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bizBean.list}" var="_row">
  <h:graphicImage
    url="#{viewModelBean.images[_row.outcome]}"
    alt="#{viewModelBean.alts[_row.outcome]}"
    title="#{viewModelBean.titles[_row.outcome]}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

`viewModelBean` could be an application-scoped type with a bunch of map properties. This assumes a relatively simple case, but the pattern is suited to more sophisticated requirements.

*Note: the repeating control should be a [NamingContainer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html), so trying to set the [client identifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getClientId%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) in the VDL is redundant. See [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/jsf-working-with-component-identifiers.html) for more.*